# Hibernate 5 migaration to Hibernate 6 @org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDefs

Tags: hibernate, jpa

i'm building an application using hibernate 6, and i'm working on the creation of some custom Types so i can use the DynamicParameterizedType.

```
 @org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDefs({
  @org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef(
     name = "monetary_amount_usd",
     typeClass = MonetaryAmountUserType.class,
     parameters = {@Parameter(name = "convertTo", value = "USD")}
 ),
 @org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef(
 name = "monetary_amount_eur",
 typeClass = MonetaryAmountUserType.class,
 parameters = {@Parameter(name = "convertTo", value = "EUR")}
 )
})
```

what's the equivalent of this code in hibernate version 6. According to the documentation, the annotations have been entirely removed, and there is no mention of any substitute or alternative.

I tried to use directly the @Convert as an alternative but i can't use paramters.